# How to access the amount of support for each class with scikit-learn, using multi-class classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am able to print a classification report using scikit-learn with the following code:

```
def predict_and_report_test(self, prediction_model):
    print(prediction_model.algorithm + ' Test')
    prediction_model.model = prediction_model.model.fit(self.X_train,  self.y_train).predict(self.X_test)
    print(classification_report(self.y_test, prediction_model.model,  target_names=None))
```

This code gives me the following output:

[image]

The problem is that classification_report returns this information in a string, so my question is: is there any simple way that scikit learn provides to access the support of each class  and perhaps store them in an array, so they can be used to plot a graph of the support for each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is precision_recall_fscore_support, which is what classification_report calls: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support

Comment: In the documentation it says that this method returns four different things if the average parameter is not None:  precision: float (if average is not None) or array of float, shape = [n_unique_labels] :

recall: float (if average is not None) or array of float, , shape = [n_unique_labels] :

fbeta_score: float (if average is not None) or array of float, shape = [n_unique_labels] :

support: int (if average is not None) or array of int, shape = [n_unique_labels] :

Comment: It doesn't explain how to actually access the support, do you know how to do this? I assume it is just going to return the accuracies of each class

Comment: it dos explain exactly how to access support. I returns a tuple of four things, the last of which is support.

Comment: Btw, you could also just do np.bincount(y)